# Trim string so it is only inside a code block

Tags: javascript, string

Pretty simple question, how would I go about cutting the code block identifier out of a string?

These strings should all have the same result:

````js
const str1 = 'Just some example text'
const str2 = '``` Just some example text```'
const str3 = '```js Just some example text```'
const str4 = '```java Just some example text```'
const str5 = '```ts Just some example text'
const result = 'Just some example text'
````

There were a few answers floating around, but none of them seemed to deal with language identifiers or relied heavily on newlines.

Comment: which are they ?

Comment: Will the language identifier always be just text? ( in `\`\`\`js` the language identifier is `js` )

Comment: @nthnchu yes, that is correct

Comment: Sorry I messed up my spelling, my bad

Comment: I think you can use some sort of regex. For example, you can see the regex that [showdown.js uses here](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/blob/f24e314a70864a3a0d1c8fb83fb131a779caeb65/src/subParsers/makehtml/githubCodeBlocks.js#L23)

Comment: Are you requiring there to always be whitespace between the ``` and the text?

Comment: I think `const result = input.replace(/```(?:\w+)?\s([^```]+)(?:```)?/, "$1")` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper answer is to use a Markdown parser.

But we can also bung something together with a regex.

````
(?:(```)([a-zA-Z]+)?\s+)?(.+)\1
````

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/Pa8dr5/1)

Pulling it apart...

````
(?:
  (```)                 # start of code, $1
  ([a-zA-Z]+)?  # code tag, maybe, $2
  \s+                 # always a space
)?                   # that's all optional
(.+)                # the content
\1                  # ends with ``` or blank
````

$1 is the code indicator, $2 is the tag, $3 is the content

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of a regex version. (That works for all of the examples and should work for anything).

````js
const input = prompt('Enter a code block:')
const output = input.match(/^(?:(?:```[a-z]*)?\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*(?:```)?)$/i)[1]
alert(output)
````

Explained (by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UaLP15/1)):

````
/^(?:(?:```[a-z]*)?\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*(?:```)?)$/i
  ^ asserts position at start of the string
    Non-capturing group (?:(?:```[a-z]*)?\s*)
      Non-capturing group (?:```[a-z]*)?
        ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
        ``` matches the characters ``` literally (case insensitive)
        Match a single character present in the list below [a-z]*
          * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
          a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case insensitive)
      \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
        * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    1st Capturing Group (.*?)
      .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
        *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    Non-capturing group (?:\s*(?:```)?)
      \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
        * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      Non-capturing group (?:```)?
        ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
        ``` matches the characters ``` literally (case insensitive)
  $ asserts position at the end of the string
Global pattern flags:
  i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
````

Comment: Note that this will match if there is no leading delimiter and only a trailing one. text``` should output text``` and not strip the ```